# Android emulator picks wrong drawable resource alias

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, emulation

I'm trying to understand how android picks drawable for different screen types.
With Android Studio 1.3, I've created a sample project with one 1 element inside `RelativeLayout` layout:

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/def" />
```

Project has 3 drawable folders:

- drawable
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-large

Emulator config is default Nexus 7 (7.02", 1200x1920, xhdpi, large, api level 22).

When I open the layout xml in android studio preview, the image is loaded from the `drawable-large` folder.
But when I build and run app in the same AVD, with same exact configuration as I select in preview, image is loaded from `drawable-xhdpi` folder, ignoring `drawable-large`, which should have higher priority.
The same thing happens if I change `drawable-large` to `drawable-sw480dp`.
I've also tried to add different values for `support-screens`, `minSdkVersion` and some other tags in manifest, but this doesn't change anything at all.

some screenshots:

- [in Preview](http://s3.postimg.org/xr422qmoz/large1.png)
- [at runtime](http://s16.postimg.org/lfll4jtol/xhdpi1.png)

What can be the cause? It there a chance that this is an emulator glitch and things will be different on real device?

Comment: Oh, thanks for formatting, dvhh!